# It does not work in tomcat servlet with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have installed tomcat with eclipse and I have a project with a servlet. Here I put the structure of both:

[image]

Until this day the steps followed to run the servlet were:

1.Press button right above the following and give "Start"
Tomcat

[image]

2.Once booted, press right button over "UsuarioServlet.java" / Run as / Run on server

[image]

Done that everything worked properly but suddenly today when doing so I get the following:

[image]

What happened?.

Comment: 404 indicates that the page does not exist. Confirm that your URL is correct.

Comment: Could be just a buggy behaviour of the Tomcat Eclipse connector. Try unzipping a Tomcat server, starting it, exporting the war file and deploying it in that Tomcat, and see if that works.

Comment: @F3RN1 can u show ur web.xml file?, problem can be ANYTHING, there is no piece of information to analyze it

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently.

Here is what helped me. 
Start tomcat and search in the console the real path where your tomcat is running. 
Go there and open `conf/server.xml`. The plug-in that integrates tomcat and eclipse adds one long line there. Scroll down to see it. Here is how this line looks on my machine.

```
  <Context docBase="C:\workspaces\work7\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ROOT" path="" reloadable="false"/><Context debug="0" docBase="C:\workspaces\work7\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\webapp" path="/mycompany-webapp-0.9-SNAPSHOT" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:webapp">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" pattern="common" prefix="access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
```

Please pay attention on path attribute. It used to be `/webapp` but now it became `/mycompany-webapp-0.9-SNAPSHOT`. So, this is the real URL where the application is deployed.

I used to surf to my application using url `http://localhost:8080/webapp`.
Now I have to use `http://localhost:8080/mycompany-webapp-0.9-SNAPSHOT`.
Alternatively I can stop server, fix the path in `server.xml` manually, start server and use the "old" URL.

The point is that this behavior  is not consistent. Sometimes (when project settings are being changed) this problem is fixed "automatically" but sometimes it returns. It happened not only on my machine but on computers of 2 other team members in company where I work.

I hope this information will help you. Good luck.

Comment: En esa linea de server.xml tengo lo siguiente:

<Context docBase="Middleware" path="/Middleware" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Middleware"/></Host>

Comment: Scroll to the right. This line is very long. And please write English. I used translate.google.com to translate your words. I do not understand Spanish.

Comment: <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
      
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." resolveHosts="false" suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="Middleware" path="/Middleware" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Middleware"/></Host>